# PowerBI connect to Azure Cosmosdb

Tags: database, import, odbc, powerbi, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I was able to get data from cosmos db to the PowerBI Desktop till this afternoon. Unfortunately it stopped working after that and showing the below error. After initial research by updating odbc drivers, it appears that the cosmosdb collection was created with higher version of the SDK than the odbc driver that PowerBI desktop supports. Could you suggest a workaround to resolve this issue.[image]